# Is it possible to share files using eth port and without crosscable?

Tags: lan

I wish to transfer huge data from my desktop to laptop both have Ubuntu 14.04. Following link mentions howto: [Problems connecting two laptops using a cross-over cable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636305/problems-connecting-two-laptops-using-a-cross-over-cable?rq=1) but this specifically needs crosscable.

Is it possible to share files using eth port and without crosscable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as at least one of the ethernet ports are Gigabit capable they should autonegotiate as GIGE does autonegotiation.   (Otherwise you can put them into a switch, but I guess thats what you are trying to avoid).

Comment: Yes I wish not use router/switch, how to check if eth port is Gigabit capable or not? does ifconfig tells about that?

Comment: I doubt ifconfig will tell you this. As thats a Linux/Unix command, you may want to try "mii-tool -v"  - if one of the capabilities are 1000baseT... then its Gigabit.

Comment: thanks @davidgo result of "mii-tool -v" is as follows           eth0      : negotiated 100baseTx-FD, link ok
basic mode:   autonegotiation enabled
which indicates autonegotiation capability. Let's try how to make connection setting and file transfer.

Comment: As said earlier "autonegotiation enabled" so I am able to connect both machines editing "Network Connections" to Manual and also able to transfer files using "smb" protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you might be able to make an ad hoc connection between the desktop and laptop without a crossover cable.
Many modern Ethernet ports have [Auto MDI-X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medium_Dependent_Interface#Auto_MDI-X), which obviates the need for a crossover cable. Only one of the two Ethernet ports needs to have the Auto MDI-X feature.  Just be sure that the Ethernet ports are set to auto-negotiate, rather than a fixed speed (which is not likely or typical).